# Sending logs to Kafka with log4j2

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I try to use log4j2 Kafka appender for sending logs to Kafka topic. 
Here is my log4j2.properties file:

```
rootLogger.level=all
rootLogger.type=asyncRoot

logger.main.name=main
logger.main.level=all
logger.main.type=asyncLogger
logger.main.appenderRefs=stdout, kafka
logger.main.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
logger.main.appenderRef.kafka.ref=KAFKA

appender.stdout.type=Console
appender.stdout.name=STDOUT
appender.stdout.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.stdout.layout.pattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%level]\t[%marker] %msg%n

appender.kafka.type=Kafka
appender.kafka.name=KAFKA
appender.kafka.bootstrap.servers=urls:host
appender.kafka.topic=topic_name
appender.kafka.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.kafka.layout.pattern="some pattern
```

When I start my with this config it failed with Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type
>   attribute provided for component bootstrap
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createComponent(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:334)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.processRemainingProperties(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:348)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createAppender(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:225)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.build(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:158)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:52)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:35)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:453)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:260)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:615)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:243)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:648)
>         at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger(LogManager.java:682)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should add `property` before the bootstrap.servers

```
appender.kafka.property.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already found solution, but I think that can be useful for someone,